# Is there a way to convert a part of an Html page that contains chart.js graphs to pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have an HTML5 page that contains some chart.js graphs. I want to add a fixed template to the pdf (header and footer) and include a specific part of the page. Is there a way that supports chart.js for this?

---

Comment: Try html2canvas or jspdf.

Comment: Thanks That was useful I used the two taking a screenshot div I wanted and genrating PDF, is it possible for jsPDF to support bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes it does support `bootstrap`.

Comment: it support basic CSS styles like colors but I can't figure out how to make it support Bootstrap style.